# Netbeans 8.2 unable to import javascript classes, even when using ECMA6

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ecmascript-6

I have a class called "Snake" written in the file "Snake.js",
another file in the same directory is called "Game.js".

The Snake class has the export identifier: `export class Snake{....}`

I'm trying to import the "Snake" class in the "Game.js" file by writing the following code at the top of "Game.js" file:
`import Snake from "./Snake.js";`

Which gives the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

This code works in Intellij Webstorm IDE but does not in Netbeans8.2 . I have tried various ways of importing the class but none of them work.

Comment: Yea... NetBeans all over again. Used it about two months and can't be happier to have switched to IntelliJ IDE's

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it:

Put `<script src="Game.js" type="module"></script>` in the header and ignore the netbeans error on type="module".